# function to send mail with phpmailer keeps loading no warning

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am testing phpmailer to send email, I created a class to send the email but the page keeps loading no warning until timeout

I created the class below, I am referencing this class in another file which is supposed to send an email on load

```
class ManageEmails
{

private $pdo;
private $mail;



public function __construct(\PDO $pdo, PHPMailer $mail)
     {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->mail = $mail;
     }

public function sendEmail($toEmail, $subject, $message, $file_path='')
    {   
        $this->mail->setFrom('info@afrojp.com', 'Darth Vader');
        $this->mail->addAddress($toEmail, 'Emperor');
        $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
        $this->mail->Body = $message;


        $this->mail->isSMTP();
        $this->mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

        $this->mail->Port = '587';

        $this->mail->SMTPAuth=true;

        $this->mail->SMTPSecure='tls';

        // need to get smtp username
        $this->mail->username = 'myemail@gmail.com';

        $this->mail->password ='appPassword';

        //we can set true if we have ssl otherwise leave blank;





        $this->mail->wrap = 50;

        $this->mail->isHTML(true);

        // if there is an attachment

        if($file_path='') $this->mail->AddAttachment($file_path);

        if($this->mail->send())
            {
                return true;
            }

        else return false;

    }
```

Then I made a call to the send mail method;

```
    require 'classes/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';


    require 'classes/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';


    require 'classes/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $manageEmails = new ManageEmails($pdo,$mail);

    $manageEmails->sendEmail('msiskasmith@gmail.com','Hello Trial', 'Whoop whoop');
```

Page keeps on loading when I expected it to send the email

Comment: Should it not be: `$manageEmails = new ManageEmails($pdo);`? Without the `$`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I put, just made a typing error here, correcting that.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: note : you shoudln't place requires inside a class. This would even break your code when you try to send out multiple mails

Comment: @Nico I have tried using googles smtp that maybe my server was the problem, tried sending through none secure connection settings, all not working.

Comment: @DarkBee could that be the problem though?

Comment: No, it's not the main issue. Is this on your localhost or on a webserver? If the latter i'd contact support asking if the ports are open

Comment: What have you tried to **really** debug the problem? Start checking which line of that code is responsible for that long runtimes. Check whether it only happens on some parameter combination

Comment: @Nico I have changed the code to use gmail smtp with 2 step verification, now I get an error 'could not authenticate'. editing the code here now to show what I have done.

Comment: @DarkBee It was an issue with both localhost and webmaster

Comment: I have edited the code, please review. By the way, the email is going when I do not include SMTP, but the issues are arising when I use smtp, so the problem should be with the smtp settings

Comment: Did you try not using `SSL`?

Comment: @DarkBee Yes I did. Sorry for the late. Just decided to send mail without SMTP.